# Get the 5 items before and after the current index in an array

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array that looks like this

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

These array represents page numbers in my scenario.
Say if I am on page 8, I'd like to create a seperate array that includes the following
The first 5 before page 8 and the first 5 after page 8.

i.e first 11 items array.

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Therefore having 11 items in an array including that page itself.

If the array is smaller than 5, then simply return the rest.

i.e

if the array looks like this `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`
and if the page is 4, since the before does not have 5 items exactly I'd like to get all of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **slice** method of the Array.

```js
function paginatorNumbers(arr, currentIndex) {
    return arr.length > 5 && currentIndex > 5
        ? arr.slice(currentIndex - 6, currentIndex + 5)
        : arr.slice(0, currentIndex + 5)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

This should work now

```
const getRange = (array, index) => {

 // You need constraints if index - 5 is < 0
 const startIndex = Math.max(0, index - 5 - 1);

 const endIndex = index+ 5;

 return array.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

}
```

Comment: Not sure how this works, if I am trying to get the first 5 items before/after the selected index. Since this only gives an option for start & end.

Comment: Sounds like a comment to me.  You may want to explain where `start` and `end` would come from.

Answer (score 0):

You can makeit very simple with Plus and Minus.

```js
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

function getRange(current) {
  let start = (current -5)
  let end = (current + 5)
  let res = []
  start = start < 0 ? 0 : start
  for(start; start <= end; start++) {
    res.push(start)
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(getRange(8)) // starts from 3
console.log(getRange(2)) // starts from 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the slice function. Given x=8 in your example, the following will create a new array with the indexes you want.

```
arr.slice(x-5, x+6)
```

The start index x-5 is inclusive (or it will include index 8-5 = 3). The end index x+6 is exclusive (it will not include index 8+6=14). So you get indices 3 - 13 like you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#slice` to generate number in a range relative to index.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
  getRangeItem = (arr, index, range) => {
    const start = Math.max(index - range - 1, 0),
          end = Math.min(index + range, arr.length),
          result = arr.slice(start, end);
    return result;
  }

console.log(getRangeItem(arr, 8, 5));
```

Comment: Instead of declaring index and range above, I think it would be esier to read if they would sit directly in the function call down below

Answer (score 0):

This is a universal solution

- count of items before and after can be set
- .slice() is used for timming the array
- checks that start index is not < 0 (otherwise it would be sliced from the end)

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

function getBeforeAfter(arr, index, count) {
   
  let start = index - count -1
  if(start < 0) start = 0
  
  let end = index + count

  return arr.slice(start, end)  
}

console.log(getBeforeAfter(arr,8,5)) // [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
```

Comment: This does not work if a array is smaller than size 5. You're assigned to a constant when that is the case.

Comment: @nardowick I just noticed, thank for mentioning

Comment: @nardowick couldn't reproduce a problem with array.length <5 - which values do you think wouldn't work?

Comment: I see you updated your answer. Using const start was failing.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method, you can get a specific subarray from the whole array. What you need to do is to slice 5 places before the page index, and then slice 5 places after the page index. Then, just [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) both subarrays and get the result.

The [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) functions are to avoid range problems when slicing the array. So, when the subarray is smaller than 5, it just returns the rest of the array, and not an empty array.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

let currentPage = parseInt(prompt("Current page"));

// page index
let i = arr.indexOf(currentPage);

// Using Math.max and Math.min to avoid range problems
const subarr = arr.slice(Math.max(i - 5, 0), i).concat(
                          arr.slice(i, Math.min(i + 6, arr.length)));

console.log(subarr);
```